# Cannot connect UIImageView with ViewController. Did they change that?

Tags: swift, swift2

This is my first time being on this forum. It's nice to be here and i really want to thank you all for the educational lessons you are giving!

So i am suffering from this issue :
i am using Xcode 7 and i did try with the latest Xcode of yosemite(6.4 version) and it seems i cannot establish an outlet connection via the old ctrl and drag method to connect a UIImageView with the ViewController. i did search the net a bit and i found some "solutions" of doing a reference to the header file but it didn't work. Did this method got removed and if yes how are we connecting now an element with the ViewController? is something wrong with my Xcode and if yes how can i fix it?

really appreciate your help!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So yeah i did manage to fix the issue. It appears there is a bug with swift and Xcode and i can tell it happens in all Xcode version 6 and up including Xcode 7. I don't know what exactly occurs this bug and i can't really link an element from scoreboard with ViewController via the simple ctrl drag and drop method but in order to fix i had to reimplent the tableView and reconfigure my elements. this did the trick and i was able to just ctrl drag and drop. if someone knows what occurs this issue please comment!!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all create outlet object

than go to storyboard or xib.

right click on file's owner (yellow box on top of xib).

you get all the outlet than click on circle right side of your outlet and map with UI by dragging the line.

hope this help you.

in this method you have to create outlet manually.

Comment: hello and first of all thank you for answering my question! To be honest i don't want to create a new outlet but to establish the outlet connection (@IBOutlet) between the UIImageView from the storyboard and the ViewController. I can't seem to be able to do that with the old traditional way of ctrl drag and connect the element with the ViewController so since i am a beginner programmer i am trying to find a way i can do that. any other ideas? thanks

Comment: sorry @Korpel because right now i'm working on xcode 6.4 with objective-c i can do that but in swift i have not tried before so let me try first than i'll be able to answering you.

Comment: in swift with xcode 6.4 same process is working with the ctrl+drag in viewcontroller is working for me in xcode 6.4.

Comment: it appeared to be a bug with the Xcode i  found the solution trying by myself some things of trying to "debug" it and it actually worked. It still works with the drag and drop in the latest Xcode version i can confirm